# RunWorkerCompleted exception not reported

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, backgroundworker, file-handling

### Background:

I am working on a service that processes 'semaphore' files.  These are txt files placed in a single directory that contain a link the an xml file that needs to be read into the database.  There was a previous version but it was careless about data loss so my new service is very careful to handle the files under any case.

### Specifics:

I have a BackgroundWorker pool that is used to a) copy new files find to a 'Processing' folder (as it is on a unix machine so copy changes the file permissions so that I can use it) and adding it to a queue and b) process the file contents.

I don't want to keep the file open so the SemaphoreFile class contains a reference to its location and manages the reading and writing of the file. It even handles the file clean up in its destructer so that even a dire crash should preserve the data.

### Expected:

In the RunWorkerCompleted method when processing the file, I expect to either get returned the semaphoreFile so that I can call the dispose method.  If all is successful then the file gets deleted and the semaphoreFile instance leaves scope.  If the process errored, which it should do in many cases, then I handle the error, mark the file as problematic (it writes the error to the file under that data and moves it to a new 'Prolematic' folder) and again, dispose().

I added the throw new NotImplementedException("No error or results"); as I need to ensure that this is never hit, so I can look for it in my debugger.  I require a reference to the semaphore file in order to tidy it up.  If I cannot do this then it will be lost.

### The Problem:

The current problem is that the background worker runs 'GetResult', which does error, but e.Error is null.  This means that e.Result is also null and I get stuck with this error that I never ever wanted to see.

Why is e.Error null when there are exceptions in SemaphoreFile.GetResults?

### Code Snippits

Execute:

```
public static void Execute()
{
    while (_isActive)
    {
        SemaphoreFile semaphoreFile;
        lock (ThreadLock)
        {
            int threadIndex;
            bool hasFreeThread = TryGetFreeThread(out threadIndex);
            bool hasSemaphore = SemaphoreQueue.HasNext;
            if (hasFreeThread && hasSemaphore)
            {
                semaphoreFile = SemaphoreQueue.Next;
                _threads[threadIndex].DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        BackgroundWorker bw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
                        if (bw.CancellationPending)
                            args.Cancel = true;
                        args.Result = semaphoreFile.GetResults(bw);
                        if (bw.CancellationPending)
                            args.Cancel = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Writelog.Write("An error occured processing file " + semaphoreFile + ":" + e.Message);
                        Writelog.WriteException(e);
                    }
                }
                ;
                _threads[threadIndex].RunWorkerCompleted += ThreadRunWorkerCompleted;
                Debug.Print("Starting Thread @ index " + threadIndex);
                _threads[threadIndex].RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RunWorkerCompleted:

```
private static void ThreadRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        if (e.Error.GetType() == typeof(SemaphoreFileException))
        {
            SemaphoreFileException semaphoreFileException = (SemaphoreFileException)e.Error;
            semaphoreFileException.SemaphoreFile.MarkAsProblematic(e.Error);
            semaphoreFileException.SemaphoreFile.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!(e.Error.GetType() == typeof(SemaphoreResultFileException)))
            {
                throw e.Error;
            }
            SemaphoreResultFileException semaphoreResultFileException = (SemaphoreResultFileException)e.Error;
            semaphoreResultFileException.SemaphoreFile.MarkAsProblematic(e.Error);
            semaphoreResultFileException.SemaphoreFile.Dispose();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!e.Cancelled)
        {
            if (e.Result == null)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("No error or results");
            }
            if (e.Result.GetType() == typeof(SemaphoreFile))
            {
                SemaphoreFile semaphoreFile = (SemaphoreFile)e.Result;
                semaphoreFile.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SemaphoreFile.GetResults

```
public SemaphoreFile GetResults(BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker)
{
    if (!File.Exists(_fileInfo.FullName))
        throw new SemaphoreFileException(this, string.Format("Semaphore {0} is missing", _fileInfo.FullName));
    if (!Parse())
        throw new SemaphoreFileException(this, string.Format("Semaphore {0} failed to parse correctly.", _fileInfo.FullName));
    if (!_resultFiles.Any())
        throw new SemaphoreFileException(this, string.Format("Semaphore {0} contains no Results.", _fileInfo.FullName));

    List<Exception> resultFileExceptions = new List<Exception>();
    foreach (ResultFile resultFile in _resultFiles)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            IsFinished = false;
            return this;
        }
        try
        {
            resultFile.Process();
            string line = resultFile.ToString();
            if (_lines.Contains(resultFile.ToString()))
            {
                _lines.Remove(line);
                if (!_lines.Contains("Lines done in last run:"))
                {
                    _lines.Add("Run @ " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                    _lines.Add("Lines done in last run:");
                }
                _lines.Add(resultFile.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            resultFileExceptions.Add(exception);
        }
    }
    if (resultFileExceptions.Count > 0)
    {
        _fileInfo = MoveFile(SemaphoreSubFoldersEnum.Problematic);
        throw new SemaphoreResultFileException(this, resultFileExceptions, string.Format("Results in Semaphore {0} contained errors:", _fileInfo.FullName));
    }
    return this;
}
```

Thanks you very much for your time ^_^

Comment: You should add a tag corresponding to the language you are using (C#?). You can do that by editing your question (edit link below your question).

Comment: whoops - thx.  still getting used to the new look.  Lost my old account too >_<

Comment: SOLVED: (and I'm an idiot)
I added error handling into my delegate and forgot to throw; it too
School boy error but one to watch out for: throw errors you want to catch *facepalms*. 
I can't answer without extra rep so if someone else wants some points they could answer this for me